# How list ManyToManyField in interactive shell?

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I'm new to Django, sorry if this is a basic question.

I need to list the values of "n_category" in a Directory.

My model is:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Category(models.Model):
    n_category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_inserted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Directory(models.Model):
    website_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    website_url = models.URLField()
    website_position = models.IntegerField()
    activated = models.BooleanField()
    date_inserted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

How can I do this in the shell?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where `directory` is an instance of `Directory`:

```
directory.categories.values_list('n_category', flat=True)
```

See the docs on [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is not working. there is another way of doing this? Best Regards,

Comment: @André What is the output or error message? "It is not working" is not very helpful :s

Comment: +1 this is very cool. @Andre this returns a list of `n_category` values for that directory instance. If by list the values you mean print the values, you would do that as follows: `for n_category in directory.categories.values_list('n_category', flat=True): ... print n_category`